# Change to DEBUG logging in HDFS (/var/logs/hadoop-yarn/apps) logs

Tags: hadoop, log4j, apache-pig

I am using cloudera CDH4 demo VM (MR2, Yarn).

I have a program flow in such a way that the jar file is executed through hadoop command, in which the main class calls the pigscript (Through pigserver registerscript method and couple of UDFs is being called in pigscript) .

I can custom log (DEBUG) into a file until the pig script is invoked.

Once the pig script is initiated, logs are getting (only INFO & WARN for the UDFs and the series of classes that are called inside UDF) saved in HDFS directory **/var/logs/hadoop-yarn/apps/(User-Name)/logs/(Job-ID)/(log-file)**.

I can see the property **yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir** as **/var/logs/hadoop-yarn/apps/** in the yarn-site.xml.

How can I change the logging to DEBUG, for that remote-app-log-dir property.

Comment: Getting the logger in EvalFunc is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005004/debugging-in-pig-udf . To configure logging in Pig you might also check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12076534/1050422